# Method from Firebase_Auth_Mocks not detected by VSCode, causing erroneous test

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, mocking, flutter-dependencies

I am currently working on an app that uses FirebaseAuth to log in into the app. While testing, I have decided to use firebase_auth_mocks 0.11.0. However, my VS Code shows that MockUserCredential does not exist.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth_mocks/firebase_auth_mocks.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

testWidgets('Signing In', (WidgetTester tester) async {
      // Create mock FirebaseAuth instance
      final mockAuth = MockFirebaseAuth();

      // Set FirebaseAuth.instance to the mock instance
      FirebaseAuthWrapper.instance = mockAuth;

      // Create a user in mock database
      const email = 'test@gmail.com';
      const password = '123456';
      final userCredential = MockUserCredential(
        user: MockUser(
          uid: 'test-user-id',
          email: email,
          )
        );
    });
```

After including the relevant package, I have tried running flutter pub get and flutter pub upgrade, and ensured that the dependencies were included. I have also tried restarting VSCode, but to no avail. In fact, the other methods such as MockFirebaseAuth(); was able to be detected, only MockUserCredentials does not. Any help on this would be appreciated!